# Grizzly captcha - please dial it back

Tags: discussion, captcha

Today, when posting response to a question I got hammered by multiple rounds of captcha. I was logged in and to get through captcha I had to disable no-script and go through MULTIPLE rounds of identifying mountains. Could we please dial it back? I would rather not have to turn off my browser security measures to post here. I already have a valid account with history - so I am already identified as a human.

Comment: I have never had to complete a captcha - where were you seeing this?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ responding to a question with 100+ words response while logged in.

Comment: I do agree that the new ReCaptcha is awful and way more annoying than the earlier "type this distorted text" ones.

Answer (score 1):

This will be down to you or your network. If there is activity from your IP that looks suspicious, it doesn't matter that you have previously identified as human, you may have to do it again.

I have had to do it on occasion when connecting from some networks, because they have generated traffic that looks unlike human traffic.

It protects us from a percentage of the spam we get hit with every single day, so I can't imagine it is going to be dialled back.